# sap .net connector 3.0 idoc processing

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector

I need to implement Idoc processing with SAP .net connector 3.0

I'm looking for C# exemples. I didn't find any help into SAP .net connector 3.0 library: SAP.Middleware.Connector !!! Amazing: no reference at all on IDOC implementation !

old classes used in SAP .net connector 2.0 (such as SAPIDocReceiver) seem to have been removed from this new version.

i heard about 'IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS' method (or class ?) which should be used in  SAP .net connector 3.0 ?

thanks to all, any help appreciated

Comment: are you trying to send idocs or do you want to receive them?

Comment: A beginning for receiving idocs with SAP .Net Connector 3 could be http://www.sign-online-solutions.net/electronic-signature/SAP_NCO3_PART_ONE.htm

Comment: "Amazing: no reference at all on IDOC implementation"  SAP is terrible about communicating with the dev and user community.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider to act as a RFC Server in NCO 3.0 and handle either 'IDOC_INBOUND_IN_QUEUE' and/or 'IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS'.

```
[RfcServerFunction(Name = "IDOC_INBOUND_IN_QUEUE")]
public static void IDOC_INBOUND_IN_QUEUE(RfcServerContext serverContext, IRfcFunction rfcFunction)
{
    //Create table to handle control records
    IRfcTable irtControl = rfcFunction.GetTable("IDOC_CONTROL_REC_40");

    //Create table to handle data records
    IRfcTable irtData = rfcFunction.GetTable("IDOC_DATA_QUEUE");

    //Process tables
    //

    //Confirm receipt of IDoc
    //BAPI call back to SAP to confirm if needed
}
```

This site may be of value http://www.dataxstream.com/